# Give reputation points to another user for their efforts?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I ran into a situation recently where I posted a question and a specific individual put in a LOT of effort to try and help me resolve the problem, but never actually found a solution.

In situations like this, is there some way I can give some of my reputation points to another person simply because they tried really hard to help?  I marked their response as the accepted answer so they got something out of it, but I'd like to give them more credit for trying.

Comment: A lot of the advice given [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52785/indicating-that-users-are-helpful-not-just-the-answer) will be useful for you. Past that, also consider offering up a bounty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come no option to 'tip' answerers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers)

Answer (score 2):

That's what the bounty system is for. Start a bounty on your question, then award it to that person. (You will have to wait a day between bounty start and accept.)

You should unaccept first to remove the acceptance, otherwise you can't start the bounty.

Other bounty info at https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: But he said the answer is *wrong*. Awarding a bounty to a wrong answer seems like a bad solution on the face of it.

Comment: @mmyers oh, I didn't see that.. for a wrong-but-nice-try answer, shouldn't an upvote suffice?

Comment: Well, an upvote is what I was going to suggest...